# Hash password after Validator::make

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to hash the password after validating the data.

My code:

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $data = Validator::make($request->only(['name', 'email', 'password']), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3:max:20',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($data->fails()) {
        //Do something
    }else{
        User::create($data);
    }
}
```

So how to hash the password after validation?

I tried to override the password inside `$data`, But it's not working

```
$data->safe()->only('password') = Hash::make($data->safe()->only('password'));
```

I can't use `$request['password']` as I won't be able to validate it and check if it's empty ..etc.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use an [Eloquent Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to automatically hash the password field when it is set.

```php
// User Model

public function setPasswordAttribute($value): void
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

I personally like this approach because you won't have to worry about it in the controllers. You can just set it once and forget about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer to your question would be to use the Eloquent `make` function.

```
$user = User::make($data);
$user->password = Hash::make($password);
$user->save();
```

Where `$password` is where ever you have the password stored.  In your case:

```
$password = $data->safe()->only('password')
```

There may be a more efficient way, based on your exact intent.  In general, the above solution will work.

The `make` function creates an Eloquent model, but does not store it in the database.  That's why you can edit the values and then call `$user->save()`

Comment: Nice idea. I will upvote and wait to see if there are other solutions

Answer (score 1):

Use a mutator method to set the password. Override the method by adding:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = 'some random password generator';
}
```

there is document:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator